# How to filter Large data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have very large data in a single table: approx. 400,000 records. The database is very poorly structured by the previous developer/company (I cannot make changes in it). It has the following columns:

1. CountryName
2. StateName (associated with countryname).
3. CityName
4. And all the other columns.

Now I have to generate a form to filter data using dropdownlists and Listview (Only Listview).

1. ddlCountry(already filled along with listview when page load)
2. ddlState(When I select country from the ddlCountry ddlState is filled and also filter records in listview)
3. ddlCity (When I select country from the ddlCountry and state from ddlState. ddlCity is filled and also filter records in listview)
   Note: URL also be changed every time I change dropdown value.

What I have done so far:

I have created the entire functionality by using stored procedures and C# code behind. I have rebinded Listview on every dropdown selected index change event. Every thing is working fine but it is taking too long to process request. My question is that is any faster way to do same thing.

---------------------------- New Update -------------------------

Database structure is like this :

TableName `myData`:

```
CountryName Nvarchar(100)  
StateName Nvarchar(100)  
CityName Nvarchar(100)  
And all the other columns
```

My queries are like this for Dropdown bind e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT StateName 
FROM myData 
WHERE CountryName = @countryName
```

To bind listview:

```
SELECT columnName1, columnName2 
FROM myData 
WHERE CountryName = @countryName AND stateName = @StateName
```

Comment: What is the bottleneck? How long does it take if you execute the SP in SSMS? If it's taking the same time you should create an appropriate index (presuming that "cannot make changes in it" doesn't include this).

Comment: What exactly is taking too long? Show the queries and database structure.

Comment: queries mention in updated question

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can fetch the data using Ajax while you display a "Loading...." message to the user.

This will not make it any faster but loading data on Page_Load and showing a blank page for long periods of time is definitely a poor user experience.